# MySQL Timer for locked row

Tags: php, mysql, cron, lamp

I am not very experienced with advanced MySQL but I was wondering what is the best way to implement a time out. I have an iPhone app that 'locks' a row in a table while it is creating the content to be written back to it. It's just a BOOL column that I toggle back and forth. The problem is, if my app crashes or they lose network connection while it is locked, it will not unlock. I would like to set a 5 minute timer or something on the server to unlock the row if they fail to complete the process within that time. My web api is written in PHP.

Can I do this with MySQL? Do I need to create a cron job?

Comment: How are you locking this row? When a session ends (lost connection), any table or row level locks are released.

Comment: I'm doing it manually, setting a column to 1 or 0. But it's using the web service as a middle man so the iphone never lets the web service know it disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a server-side application (cron job could work) that periodically looks at rows with a lock and unlocks them if they've expired. To know whether they have expired, you need to include a datetime column which is set to the current time when the lock is applied.

Alternatively, you can skip the server-side app and just let your iPhone app check the datetime, and reset the lock if it's been long enough.

In either case, the key is to add a datetime column and utilize that to know the age of the lock.

Comment: That's a great idea I'm going to implement your second suggestion. I'd rather have less applications running on the server